# How to ignore changes for specific tags names with spaces using Azure Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I need to ingore below tags that starts `hidden-link: ...`.

```
 ~ tags = {
            ...
            "UsedBy" = "user@email.com"
            ...

          - "hidden-link: /app-insights-instrumentation-key" = "XXX" -> null
          - "hidden-link: /app-insights-resource-id"         = "YYY" -> null
            
        }
```

Please note, the tags key name contains spaces so can't use:

```
lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      tags.hidden-link: /app-insights-instrumentation-key
      ]
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried: `tags["hidden-link: /app-insights-instrumentation-key"]` and `tags["hidden-link: /app-insights-resource-id"]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the terraform documentation for the lifecycle meta-argument [`ignore_changes` option](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle#ignore_changes), the way to ignore particular tags is:

> Map and list elements can be referenced using index notation, like `tags["Name"]` and `list[0]` respectively.

Based on the way tags from the question are defined, the way to ignore them would be:

```
tags["hidden-link: /app-insights-instrumentation-key"]
tags["hidden-link: /app-insights-resource-id"]
```